# Information theoretic substitute for precision and recall?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

Is there a substitute for measuring precision, recall of a classifier (binary or multi-class) to evaluate its performance using information-theoretic quantities like entropy, mutual information or normalized mutual information?